# Add travelling time in ms project 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

When I do a project timeline, there will be a workshop at client office, usually it's 400km away from our office. In my timeline, I would like to add the travelling time (eg. 1 day before workshop and 1 day after workshop), without creating activity in the timeline.

Similar to lag, which add after the activity, but I need to add it before the activity, without overlapping with predecessor task (lead).

Appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply link the two tasks together and put a one day lag between.  However, I understand, and I am not sure why this occurs, that having leads and lags in your horizontal logic can hose up critical path calculations.  Therefore, I would suggest putting your travel time as an activity and then link everything together with zero leads and lags.  There must be a reason why you do not want the travel time as an activity; however, I cannot think of what that might be.

Comment: Noted. The reason is because person who update the timeline is not the same person who prepared the timeline. Seems like the best option is add specific activity for travelling. Thanks a bunch David!